# What is the best way in jQuery Mobile to change to another page (inside the same HTML file) immediately after browsing to a URL?

Tags: jquery-mobile

My jQuery Mobile (1.3.2) website uses parameters in the URL hash value to decide which page (`<div data-role="page">` in the single HTML file) to display.

I currently use:

```
<body onload="myns.initialize()">
```

where `myns.initialize()` parses the URL hash value, and then uses `$.mobile.changePage()` to change to the appropriate ("internal") page:

```
myns.initialize = function() {                       
  getContextFromURL(); // Populate context object
  // If the parameters in the hash do not specify an action,
  // go to the "menu" (list of actions)
  if (context.action) {                             
    // Populate contents of default page (for specific action)
    setAction(context.action);                      
  } else {                                          
    $.mobile.changePage("#menu", {                  
      transition: "none"                            
    });                                             
  }                                                 
}
```

This works, but I suspect it's not the best way to do it.

The current default page (the first `<div data-role="page">` in the one-and-only HTML file) is one of the possible pages, depending on the parameters in the hash.

The static HTML tags for the default page consist of a header div (containing a title, which for now is common across pages, and some icons, which aren't) and an empty content div (that gets dynamically populated; again, depending on the hash parameters):

```
<div data-role="page" id="action">                             
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#menu"                                            
      class="ui-icon-nodisc"                                   
      data-role="button"                                       
      data-icon="bars"                                         
      data-iconshadow="false"                                  
      data-iconpos="notext">Actions</a>                        
    <h1>Title</h1>                        
    <a href="#"                                                
      onclick="myns.showInfo()"                                 
      class="ui-icon-nodisc"                                   
      data-role="button"                                       
      data-icon="info"                                         
      data-iconshadow="false"                                  
      data-iconpos="notext">Information</a>                    
  </div>                                                       
  <div data-role="content" id="content">                       
  </div>                                                       
</div>
```

If the hash parameters dictate that another page should be displayed instead of this default page, then `myns.initialize()` changes to that appropriate page.

This works, but it is inelegant. I can sometimes see the header icons (that are specific to the default page) briefly appearing, and then disappearing (if the eventual page does not contain those header icons).

I've tried specifying a new almost-blank default page, like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="default-page">                       
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Title</h1>                        
  </div>                                                       
  <div data-role="content"/>                                   
</div>
```

in front of the original default page, but - and here I get an inkling that my current working approach might actually be deeply flawed, and based on a too-shallow understanding - the `changePage()` calls in `myns.initialize()` (including a new `changePage()` call for what used to be the default page) no longer change to the appropriate page. I have confirmed that the `changePage()` calls occur (by the blunt instrument of temporarily inserting `alert()` functions before and after those calls), but no page change actually occurs. The almost-blank default page remains. So, for now, pending a better answer, I have fallen back on my working "default page is one of the eventual candidate pages" approach.

I suppose I could dynamically adjust the default page so that it becomes the appropriate page depending on the hash parameters, but I'm hoping for a more straightforward solution. Some of the candidate pages are more-or-less static (well, "pro formas" with variable details that I dynamically inject via script). I'd like to be able to just "go to" those pages (rather than, for example, writing bespoke code that manipulates the DOM to copy the HTML for those pages into the default page).

Added some hours later: I woke up with a hunch about that new default page. Specifically, this empty div element:

```
<div data-role="content"/>
```

I changed it to explicitly specify a start tag and an end tag:

```
<div data-role="content"></div>
```

That fixed the problem: the `changePage()` calls in my `myns.initialize()` now work.

This new almost-blank default page avoids the flickering header icon issue. Still, it's inelegant, and I'd like a better answer.

Comment: Why is all this needed? am I missing something here? if the url hash has a valid page id jQuery Mobile will automatically load that page instead of the default (first page on DOM)

Comment: The URL hash does not have a valid page ID.

Comment: @koala_dev, the hash consists of parameters, similar to this:

    #action=dothis&parm1=withis&parm2=andthis

My site uses these parameters to determine which page to display. For example, if the action parameter is missing, rather than displaying a page that is specific to an action (and, perhaps, combination of other parameters), the site displays a menu of actions.

In case you're wondering, I am deliberately using parameters in the URL hash rather than the query string. (Feel free to ask why, but it's not directly related to this question.)

Comment: @koala_dev, for completeness, I guess I should also mention that my script stops jQM changing the hash: `$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() { $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false; });`

Comment: I was premature writing "That fixed the problem" (in my question, under "Added some hours later"). Converting the `<div/>` into explicit start and end tags fixed the problem in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9, but not Safari. I finally found the answer (at least, it now works in Safari, too): I added `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` to `mobileinit` (I noticed that Safari _was_ displaying the correct page, then immediately flicking back to the almost-blank default page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to the [`pagebeforechange`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/) event which is the most suited for handling changes in the navigation, you just need to set the value of `data.toPage` to the page you want to show:

`$(document).on("pagebeforechange", myns.initialize);`

```
myns.initialize = function(e, data) {                       
  getContextFromURL(); // Populate context object
  // If the parameters in the hash do not specify an action,
  // go to the "menu" (list of actions)
  if (context.action) {                             
    // Populate contents of default page (for specific action)
    setAction(context.action);                      
  } else {                                          
    data.toPage = $('#menu');                            
  }                                                 
}
```

Note: If you only need this function on page load you could use `one()` instead of `on()` to execute the handler only once

Comment: thank you for taking the time to look at this.

I've tried your suggestion, but I get a blank page with an endless "loading" overlay. I've only done limited debugging; the function
pointed to by `one()` does get called, but an `alert()` function that I inserted after the `toPage()` calls never gets called.

Also, I'm too much of a jQ/jQM/JavaScript newbie to understand why
using `$(document).one("pagebeforechange",...)` and `data.toPage()` is better than using `<body onclick="...">` and `$.mobile.changePage()` (my current method, which, while I don't claim is best practice, works).

Comment: @GrahamHannington well the difference between the two methods is that by handling the beforechangeevent the default page won't load so you won't get that flickering of the default content being shown before being replaced by the contents of the page you wanted to show... for debugging, did you check the console for any errors?  also I assume you orginally had some `changePage()` calls inside `setAction`, did you replace thos for `data.toPage`, also note that toPage is not a function but a property, finally are you using the latest version of jQuery Mobile?

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Yes, that is a definite improvement (not loading the default page), thank you. No, I hadn't checked the console. If I had, I would have noticed that I'd forgotten to change `function()` to `function(e, data)`. Sorry. Works great now. I note that an `alert()` function inside a `<script>` element directly in that "bypassed" default page _does_ get called, but the page itself does not seem to get rendered (no apparent flickering). I'm accepting this answer; thanks again!

Comment: @GrahamHannington glad to hear it worked for you :) about the `alert()`, I believe any javascript code that you place inside any page (default or not) will get executed as the DOM is rendered, that's why you have to handle specific page scripts with bindings to the jQM events